# How can I build a exception report in google analytics 4

Tags: javascript, exception, google-analytics

I'm new to using google analytics beyond basic pageView/navigation data. I've implemented exception logging as described https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/exceptions .

I see these `exception` in https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/ under the `All Events`. When I click through I see them logged:

[image]

but I have no idea how to build a report, where I can get emails with their details as they happen, or hit a specific thresh-hold.

In the past I've used https://sentry.io/ to explore this sort of data, but I'm looking for a free way to accomplish something similar.

Thank you in advance for any direction on this ‍♂️

Comment: I could only plot event count but not get a table of error descriptions. Apparently you need to use BigQuery for that https://www.optizent.com/how-to-see-event-parameters-in-google-analytics-4-reports/

Comment: This is very frustrating, in UA you used to be able to report on full exception descriptions. GA4 you can only see concatenated exception descriptions from the last 30 mins! Yes, not even the whole description!  I'm not sure why this page exists https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/exceptions if you can't retrieve / query this data :(

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom dimensions (which are event scoped) and use those in the reports. Note that you can create upto 50 such event scoped dimensions as of Jul-2023.

Please note that high cardinality data such as browser-string/userid/ip are not advised for custom dimensions.

This article [describes it in detail](https://www.rootandbranchgroup.com/ga4-event-parameters/)

PS: I am still waiting to see actual data populated as it might take some time after creting a new custom dimension.